# IEnumerable.Except wont work, so what do I do?

Tags: c#, linq

I have a linq to sql database. Very simplified we have 3 tables, Projects and Users. There is a joining table called User_Projects which joins them together.

I already have a working method of getting `IEnumberable<Project>` for a given user.

```
from up in User_Projects
select up.Project;
```

Now I want to get the projects the user *isn't* involved with. I figured the except method of IEnumerable would be pretty good here:

```
return db.Projects.Except(GetProjects());
```

That compiles, however I get a runtime error: "Local sequence cannot be used in LINQ to SQL implementation of query operators except the Contains() operator."

Is there any way to get around this?

---

### Update:

A few views but no answers :p

I have tried this:

```
        IEnumerable<Project> allProjects = db.Projects;
        IEnumerable<Project> userProjects = GetProjects();
        return allProjects.Except(GetProjects());
```

I know it's essentially the same as the original statement - but now i dont get a runtime error. Unfortunately, it doesn't really do the except part and just returns all the projects, for some reason

Comment: I edited my answer to include a quick explanation of why you have to do it that way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Linq to Sql doesn't understand how to work with an arbitrary in-memory sequence of objects. You need to express this in relational terms, which works on IDs:

```
var userProjectIds =
    from project in GetProjects()
    select project.ProjectId;

var nonUserProjects =
    from project in db.Projects
    where !userProjectIds.Contains(project.ProjectId)
    select project;
```

Comment: Yup this did it, it's pretty lame that Except() didnt work though :(

Comment: @Bryan Watts, you just changed my quality of life significantly with the statement "Linq to Sql doesn't undertand how to work with an arbitrary in-memory sequence of objects." Thank you

Comment: @UB3571: That is quite a compliment. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You could try something simple like

```
User u = SomeUser;

from up in User_Projects
where up.User != u
select up.Project;
```

Comment: FAR better, but it needs a distinct.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
var userProjects = GetProjects();
return db.Projects.Except(userProjects.ToArray());
```

The ToArray should force evaluation of the sequence (if I'm understanding the issue right) and allow the operation to succeed.