# Best Practice: Convert LINQ Query result to a DataTable without looping

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, datatable

What is the best practice to convert LINQ-Query result to a new `DataTable`?
can I find a solution better than `foreach` every result item?

**EDIT**
 AnonymousType

```
var rslt = from eisd in empsQuery
           join eng in getAllEmployees()
           on eisd.EMPLOYID.Trim() equals eng.EMPLOYID.Trim()
           select new
           {
               eisd.CompanyID,
               eisd.DIRECTID,
               eisd.EMPLOYID,
               eisd.INACTIVE,
               eisd.LEVEL,
               eng.EnglishName
           };
```

**EDIT 2:**
I got exception:

> Local sequence cannot be used in LINQ to SQL implementation of query operators except the Contains() operator.

as I try to execute the query
and found the solution here [IEnumerable.Except wont work, so what do I do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/331345/ienumerable-except-wont-work-so-what-do-i-do) 
 and [Need linq help](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/linqprojectgeneral/thread/403d2e05-af6b-4300-ba7b-79588e6b779c)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Use Linq to Dataset. From the MSDN : [Creating a DataTable From a Query (LINQ to DataSet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386921.aspx))

```
// Query the SalesOrderHeader table for orders placed 
// after August 8, 2001.
IEnumerable<DataRow> query =
    from order in orders.AsEnumerable()
    where order.Field<DateTime>("OrderDate") > new DateTime(2001, 8, 1)
    select order;

// Create a table from the query.
DataTable boundTable = query.CopyToDataTable<DataRow>();
```

If you have anonymous types :

From the Coder Blog : [Using Linq anonymous types and CopyDataTable](http://www.thecoderblog.com/2008/10/14/using-linq-anonymous-types-and-copytodatatable-to-avoid-excess-database-calls/)

It explains how to use MSDN's [How to: Implement CopyToDataTable Where the Generic Type T Is Not a DataRow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb669096.aspx)

Comment: what if the query was contains 'select new {fld1, fld2, fld3}' then it cant convert it to IEnumerable?

Comment: http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2007/05/09/Converting-an-object-collection-to-a-DataSet.aspx

Answer (score 4):

Converting Query result in DataTables Generic Function

```
 DataTable ddt = new DataTable();

 ddt = LINQResultToDataTable(query);

    public DataTable LINQResultToDataTable<T>(IEnumerable<T> Linqlist)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();


        PropertyInfo[] columns = null;

        if (Linqlist == null) return dt;

        foreach (T Record in Linqlist)
        {

            if (columns == null)
            {
                columns = ((Type)Record.GetType()).GetProperties();
                foreach (PropertyInfo GetProperty in columns)
                {
                    Type colType = GetProperty.PropertyType;

                    if ((colType.IsGenericType) && (colType.GetGenericTypeDefinition()
                    == typeof(Nullable<>)))
                    {
                        colType = colType.GetGenericArguments()[0];
                    }

                    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn(GetProperty.Name, colType));
                }
            }

            DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();

            foreach (PropertyInfo pinfo in columns)
            {
                dr[pinfo.Name] = pinfo.GetValue(Record, null) == null ? DBNull.Value : pinfo.GetValue
                (Record, null);
            }

            dt.Rows.Add(dr);
        }
        return dt;
    }
```

Comment: Please add some explanation

Answer (score 2):

I am using morelinq.2.2.0 package in asp.net web application, Nuget package manager console

```
PM> Install-Package morelinq
```

Namespace

```
using MoreLinq;
```

My sample stored procedure sp_Profile() which returns profile details

```
DataTable dt = context.sp_Profile().ToDataTable();
```

Answer (score 1):

Use System.Reflection and iterate for each record in the query object.

```
Dim dtResult As New DataTable
Dim t As Type = objRow.GetType
Dim pi As PropertyInfo() = t.GetProperties()

For Each p As PropertyInfo In pi
    dtResult.Columns.Add(p.Name)
Next
Dim newRow = dtResult.NewRow()
For Each p As PropertyInfo In pi
    newRow(p.Name) = p.GetValue(objRow,Nothing)
Next
dtResult.Rows.Add(newRow.ItemArray)
Return dtResult
```

Answer (score -1):

Try 
Datatable dt= (from rec in dr.AsEnumerable() select rec).CopyToDataTable()