# Loading query.CopyToDataTable() to a DataTable

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I wrote a Cross Join query for two DataTables in Linq. I am not able to load the query to DataTable. CopyToDataTable is throwing an exception. What would be the solution to load a DataTable from query ( Collection Object ).

```
  var query =
                    from dt1 in dtInvoiceHeader.AsEnumerable()
                    from dt2 in dtInvoiceDetail.AsEnumerable()
                    select new 
                    {
                        dt1, dt2 
                    };

                // Create a table from the query.

              // DataTable dtReports = query.CopyToDataTable();
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best Practice: Convert LINQ Query result to a DataTable without looping](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4460654/best-practice-convert-linq-query-result-to-a-datatable-without-looping)

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386921.aspx. Please refer the link.

Comment: On reading the examples of Best Practice, i tried with IEnumerable<DataRow> query . But <DataRow> syntax is not allowing crossjoin. It is not allowing the second of DataTable

Comment: I have two datatables which doesn't have datarelation column. I have to use Crossjoin query to get a single datatable.