# how to pass linq query in datatable

Tags: entity-framework, datatable

I want to collect all rows and pass it to datatable. My linq query:

```
var queryAll = from all in db.tblMake select all ;
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
```

How can i pass the queryAll into datatable dt?

If i try :

```
 IEnumerable<DataRow> queryAll = from all in db.tblMake.AsEnumerable() select all;
```

comes with error:

```
 Cannot Implicitely Convert type 'System.Collection.Generic.IEnumerable<Workshop2s.Models.tblMake>' to 'System.Collection.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Data.DataRow>'
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4460654/best-practice-convert-linq-query-result-to-a-datatable-without-looping

Comment: Thnx for response. But if i try like this  IEnumerable<DataRow> queryAll = from all in db.tblMake.AsEnumerable() select all;
comes with the error 
'Cannot Implicitely Convert type 'System.Collection.Generic.IEnumerable<Workshop2s.Models.tblMake> to 'System.Collection.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Data.DataRow>'

Comment: have you read this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386921.aspx